Target class [admin] does not exist. Laravel 11
I'm new to coding and I'm currently working on a project where I'm encountering an error that's preventing me from moving forward. Note that I had to add the Kernel.php file manually because it did not install when I created my Laravel project.
I am working with Laravel 11.
I am getting the error: Target class [admin] does not exist.
Here is web.php :
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
return view('back.dashboard');
})-\>middleware(\['auth', 'verified', 'admin'\])-\>name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')-\>group(function () {
Route::get('/profile', \[ProfileController::class, 'edit'\])-\>name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile', \[ProfileController::class, 'update'\])-\>name('profile.update');
Route::delete('/profile', \[ProfileController::class, 'destroy'\])-\>name('profile.destroy');
});

Here is Kernel.php :
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'precognitive' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    'checkRole' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
];

Here is the middleware Admin.php :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Admin extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($user && str_contains($user->role, 'admin')){
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403, 'Accès non autorise');

    }
}

I have checked the name to see if I might have misspelled it, and I have verified that the files are in the correct folders. Everything seems to be in order.

Welcome to an English site

run composer dump-autoload

Thank you N69S but I ran composer dump-autoload and I still get the same error ("Target class [admin] does not exist") after refreshing my page :/

Laravel 11 removed Kernel.php.
You now have to register middleware through bootstrap/app.php
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#middleware-aliases

Thank you, I didn'y know this information. But I did it, I removed Kernel.php and here is my app.php now :
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->alias(['admin', \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdminRole::class]);
})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    //
})->create(); ``


I still have the same error..

You have to define it as a key => value: $middleware->alias(['admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdminRole::class]);
You should also remove extends Middleware from your middleware.

Remove extends Middleware from the Admin.php file.

Try using different file name like 'CheckAdminRole'. Thanks.

Thank you for your help. I tried changing my Admin middleware to CheckAdminRole. I also modified the Kernel to use 'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdminRole::class, but it still doesn't work.

Then try to clear cache and restart the server.
